# Auto increment over multiple identity columns in MS SQL 2005 or 2008

Tags: sql-server, database-design, identity, auto-increment, multiple-tables

I want to have two different tables in MS SQL, for example users and groups, both with identity column. It is possible to create auto increment over two identity columns? I want to have third table with common informations to these two tables and I want to identify unique record.

In Oracle is SEQUENCE.

It is possible to do it?

Thanks,

Martin Pilch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, SQL Server does not have a concept where you can use a *named identity* in multiple tables (cfr. Oracles `SEQUENCE`)

**You have a few options to differentiate the data coming from both tables**

- Use a [GUID](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1600) as your ID column in both tables.
- In your third table, manipulate the ID of one of both tables resulting again in a unique ID (Multiply with -1 for instance). *I am assuming your third table would be a view on both other tables.*
- Rethink your design as to why you would need such a construct.

If the design can't be changed, using a GUID would be my choice of preference.

Comment: GUID is the solution but it is too big - 16Bytes. I will try to solve it another way

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you got [Identity property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(SQL.80).aspx).

Your third table should reference users and groups via [foreign key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx).

To achieve uniqueness of both columns in your third table, simply use unique constraint, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Third (
  id_user INT references Users(id),
  id_group INT references Groups(id),
  CONSTRAINT user_group_unique UNIQUE(id_user, id_group)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for, but you can have auto increment fields in SQL Server using the [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) property:

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees
(
 id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),
 fname varchar (20),
 minit char(1),
 lname varchar(30)
);
```

In the above example (taken from the linked page), the `id_num` field will auto increment, starting with a seed of 1 and incrementing it by 1.

You can have such a field on each table and a many-to-many table that links the two.